# How can I do this? nope

Tags: iphone

Is there any possible way

I know it doesn't make sense at the first sight but can I do it somehow?

p

Comment: Well did you read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#In-order?

Comment: Please show us what you have already and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Inorder traversal only makes sense for *binary* trees. If you have N child nodes what is "inorder" supposed to mean?

Comment: An in-order tree infers that an in-order traversal on that tree would produce a sorted list, as the tree is ordered on some sort of mechanic, like a binary search tree with it's left and right pattern. If your 'general' tree has an ordering mechanic for adding data in-order, then that same logic should be applied. If there isn't order in the tree, then there isn't a logical equivalent, unless you want to arbitrarily process the first half of child nodes completely before processing its second half.

Comment: @MarcoAugello: Of course it's not impossible -- just visit the current node whenever you feel like. But it's meaningless to call it "inorder" unless there is a well-defined relationship between the child nodes and the parent. In which case, use that relationship as a guide.

Answer (score 2):

InOrder traversal for a general tree doesn't really make sense.  Since there is no "Order" in which you should visit the current node.  InOrder only makes sense for binary tree's.

For InOrder to make sense for a general tree you would have to define what order the current node should be visited in.  Since the only two choices that make any sense would be to visit the current node first (which is Pre-Order) or last (which is Post-Order).  Therefore InOrder for a general tree doesn't really make much sense.

Of course if your general tree has a specific structure then InOrder can make sense.  If you always have the first 3 children are left and all others are right then your algorithm looks like this...

```
inorder(node)
  if node == null then return
  inorder(node.first)
  inorder(node.second)
  inorder(node.third)
  visit(node)
  foreach (remainingNode in RemainingNodes)
     inorder(remainingNode)
```

Generic code as extension method...

```
    static public IEnumerable<Node<T>> InOrder<T>(this Node<T> thisNode)
    {
        var list = new List<Node<T>>();
        IEnumerable<Node<T>> leftNodes;
        IEnumerable<Node<T>> rightNodes;
        if (thisNode.Children == null)
        {
            leftNodes = new List<Node<T>>();
            rightNodes = new List<Node<T>>();
        }
        else
        {
            leftNodes = thisNode.Children.Take((int)Math.Ceiling(thisNode.Children.Count() / 2.0)).ToList();
            rightNodes = thisNode.Children.Skip(leftNodes.Count()).ToList();
        }
        if (leftNodes.Any())
        {
            foreach (var child in leftNodes)
            {
                list.AddRange(child.InOrder());
            }
        }
        list.Add(thisNode);
        if (rightNodes.Any())
        {
            foreach (var child in rightNodes)
            {
                list.AddRange(child.InOrder());
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Comment: Use your count method on your collection of child nodes to determine how many children go before and how many go after.

Comment: What do you mean a generic version?  This doesn't assume anything except that you have a collection of nodes and a property called Name.  Replace Console.WriteLine with whatever you need to do to visit the node.

Comment: Please post your code in your question statement.  That will make it easier to help.

Comment: I see the link but SO guidelines suggest you put the code into the question in order for it to benefit the rest of the community

Comment: The code above doesn't have the return type you want in it... please fix it so I can know what exactly you want returned.

Comment: It still doesn't look right... but it looks like you have it as an extension method?

Answer (score 1):

An In-Order traversal requires that the nodes be visited in the order

1. left
2. this
3. right

For non-binary trees, such behavior does not make sense because there is no left or right dedicated node. As Kevin said, it only *really* makes sense to perform pre- or post-order traversal; however, if you want to perform an In-Order-esque traversal, you could visit half the children nodes, this node, and then the other half. This isn't really in the spirit of an in-order traversal, though.

For example, let's say your node has 5 children. This would make the in order traversal:

1. child 1
2. child 2
3. child 3
4. this
5. child 4
6. child 5

(Just for sake of argument. Technically, child 3 and this could swap, but the same problem will arise)

If child 5 is then removed, the in order traversal would be:

1. child 1
2. child 2
3. this
4. child 3
5. child 4

and the inherent order has changed.

However, if you were to maintain two lists of children: one being your `leftChildren` and the other being `rightChildren`, then an in-order traversal would make as much sense as it does in a binary tree. How you choose which child goes in which list, though, is another problem entirely.

EDIT: Since it appears you want to go ahead with this, you can do it using something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Node<T>> InOrder()
{
    if (Children != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Children.length; i++)
        {
            if (i == Children.length / 2)
            {
                yield return this;
            }

            foreach (var node in Children[i].InOrder())
            {
                yield return node;
            }
        }
    }
}
```